# I'd like all files created in a specific directory to be owned by a certain user in linux, is that possible?

Tags: linux, permissions

First I've been asked to change the owner of the current files in the folder and i chown'ed -R the path but i want to be sure that files which will be created there in the future will also be owned by the same user.

Comment: You probably don't want to do that because then users can give away files that they can't take back. Whatever your outer problem is, it's probably better solved by group ownership of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to the be able to share files seamlessly between a group of users, on Linux you can set the 'set group id' bit on the directory:

chmod 2777 /shared

or

chmod g+s /shared

To make the files actually be owned by your user you would have to do some scripting.
For example, running this [find command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories) suggested on wikipedia via a cron entry every minute.